# RuntimeException when calling SQLException.getMessage() (DB2)

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

We are seeing a `RunTimeException` when calling `SQLException.getMessage()` with DB2:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ro: Q1D02E02;EXECUTE;SYSIBM.SQLCAMESSAGECCSID
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:676)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.p.e(p.java:512)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.p.a(p.java:467)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.sn.a(sn.java:334)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.qm.c(qm.java:78)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ro.getMessage(ro.java:52)
```

It's probably caused my a config issue, but `getMessage()` surely shouldn't throw?

Comment: Which Db2-driver version?  Which Db2-server operating-system?   Is jdbc driver propery 'retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage' set ?  If it is set , and your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, then it will call the stored procedure and yes that can throw exceptions if your configuration is incorrect, for example if the connecting userid lacks execute rights on the relevant stored procedure

Comment: I'll dig out the details (it's not my system). But even if the user lacks permissions, the method never ever should throw, right?

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that it is ok to throw a RunTimeException in this case?

Comment: If Db2-server is being asked "please do x for user y" , and the Db2-server is not configured to allow user y to do x, then it seems valid for the Db2-server to throw an exception. The client (jdbc driver) can choose what it wants to do with that exception of course, which includes discarding it...but that is a matter for the jdbc driver and its configuration, hence knowing the details of versions etc becomes necessary...

Comment: I agree. What I'm saying is that it's clearly a bug in the JDB driver. And yes, I'll try to get information about the concrete version.

Comment: Not necessarily a bug, but configuration. if the jdbc client is configured to retrieve message details from the Db2-server (which is not the default usually), then it seems  equally valid for the jdbc client to throw an exception after a server-error in this case.

Comment: Also, the database in question seems to have been created as restrictive, otherwise execute privileges on `SYSIBM.SQLCAMESSAGECCSID` would be [granted to `PUBLIC`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0005824.html).

Comment: What I'm saying is that no matter how access rights are configured, `SQLException.getMessage()` never ever should throw an expection.

Comment: Does the spec for `java.lang.Throwable` specify that `getMessage()` can _not_ throw its own exception?

Comment: ...never ever should throw an exception unless it's out of the implementer's control (such as OutOfMemory). @IanBjorhovde - you win in spec-lawyering, but I don't think this is helpful. Problems like these waste enormous time for developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Db2 JDBC driver property [`retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvjcerr.html) is set to `true` (non-default value), the driver will attempt to retrieve the complete error message from the server by calling the stored procedures `SYSIBM.SQLCAMESSAGE` and `SYSIBM.SQLCAMESSAGECCSID`.

Normally the `EXECUTE` privilege on these procedures would be granted to `PUBLIC`, but your user ID Q1D02E02 doesn't appear to have that privilege. This could happen, for example, if the database has been created as restrictive, or if the privilege was explicitly revoked from `PUBLIC`.

To resolve the problem either grant the necessary privilege or avoid retrieving error messages from the database server.

Comment: Accepting this as answer as it describes how to resolve the issue. However, what I'm *really* interested in is whether this is a bug in the JDBC driver, and whether it actually is going to be fixed. IBM?

Comment: Clearly this is not a bug -- you have to explicitly enable this property if you want the driver to talk to the server, which you obviously did, so the problem is of your own doing.

Comment: @JulianReschke I would suggest that you open a PMR with IBM on this issue. Even with IBMers here on SO it's not necessarily something that will be evaluated as a defect unless it's present in their systems.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde - that requires a support contract, right?